# multiple versions of python, how to install python package on a specific version?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a remote machine with Python 2.6 installed. I then installed python 2.7 using these instructions [python install](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/). I then set up an alias so scripts will use 2.7 in future.

How do I install numpy to python 2.7.

Comment: `pip2.7 install numpy`, if you also installed `pip`. Otherwise using the correct alias/python when installing from source, you can do `python setup.py install` and it will be installed in `<prefix>/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: aah you can do that...?

Comment: Python keeps track of its major versions by using `lib/pythonx.y` directories for packages. If you also installed python itself with `make altinstall`, it won't even overwrite the current default `python` command (can be safer for your system), and you'll only get things like `python2.7` as commands.

Comment: For more control over what's installed for what, use a `virtualenv`, then you can specify the Python interpreter version to use and install specific tools for specific tasks.

Comment: What is the alias you used? Not a link I suppose? Because the latter could mess around with system scripts (depending on your OS); although Python 2.7 should be compatible with 2.6 scripts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I find virtualenv useful for developing and testing against version, but at times I find virtualenv overrated. Here, I think the OP just wanted to upgrade the Python version, and install the corresponding numpy in a correct way. Doesn't sound like virtualenv is needed for that.

Comment: Apologies so python 2.6 was the default package on the machine. I installed numpy using `yum install numpy`. I then installed python 2.7 using the instructions at the link in the directory /usr/src/. I then put this alias "alias python=/usr/src/Python-2.7.8/python" in ~/.bashrc. So numpy is already installed on the machine but python 2.7 can't pick it up? Should I uninstall it? How do I install it for version 2.7. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
python2.7 -m pip install numpy
```

Should do the trick